# json_graph.node_link_data gives incorrect ID's in links

Tags: python, d3.js, networkx

I want to display a graph in d3.js that has been built up in python/networkx (force directed graph). I noticed that the serialized json only works if the nodes have been created with a number as ID starting at 0.
Below I give the smallest piece of my code that still shows this phenomenon:

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.readwrite import json_graph

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node(1)
G.add_node(2)
G.add_edge(1,2)


print (list(G.nodes()))
print (list(G.edges())) 
data = json_graph.node_link_data(G)
print(data)

# output:
[1, 2]   # the nodes
[(1, 2)]  # the edge between the 2 nodes
{'links': [{'source': 0, 'target': 1}], 'nodes': [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}], 'multigraph': False, 'directed': False, 'graph': {}}
```

The properties of the links shows the problem: 'source':0 and 'target':1 but the ID's of the nodes are 1 and 2.

After serialization the link is described as a connection between nodes with ID's 0 and 1 although there ID's have been defined as 1 and 2.
I have tried quite a few things, but basically the links use ID's starting at 0. So unless my nodes are following the same numbering, the links are not correct in the serialization.

I cannot imagine it should work like this, or am I making a mistake?

Comment: I don't understand your problem: if you don't specify the ID, the default accessor will specify the nodes as a zero based index. So, you should have no problem: 0 --> 1 would link the nodes with id=1 and id=2, because the id doesn't matter anymore.

Comment: The problem really arises when the json is read into d3.js when only nodes are displayed but no connections between them (that was what I spotted in the beginning and traced back to the inconsistent id's).

Comment: In your answer you suggest it is possible to specify the ID. I am not sure what you mean. I have tested including {'id':'name', 'source':'from', 'target':'to'} in the node_link_data command. The output is now:
{'nodes': [{'name': 1}, {'name': 2}], 'graph': {}, 'multigraph': False, 'directed': False, 'links': [{'from': 0, 'to': 1}]}.
So I can 'relable'' the tags but the incorrect IDs remain.